# Detecting which extended sprited i touched

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want detect which object of Card I touched. Card is custom Class which extends cocos Sprite.

I would like to call member methods on card. Something like this: if (target is Card) target.openCard();

Thank you very much in advance.

Main Class Body

```
bool HelloWorld::init()    
{

... some init code, generating card arrays, shuffling

// draw memory cards
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        auto card = Card::createCard();
        card->customInit(cardsPictures[count]);
        this->addChild(card);

        card->setPosition(100 + i*100, 600 - j*100);

        count++;
    }

}

// register event listener
auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchEnded, this);
touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchMoved, this);
touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchCancelled, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);

return true;
}

bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    auto target = event->getCurrentTarget();

    if (target is Card) target.openCard(); // not working

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(target is Card)
```

That doesn't look like C++ to me. What is it ? :D

First:
Is target a pointer ? If so do:

```
target->openCard(); // instead of target.openCard();
```

Anyway, if you want to call methods on an object that you are CERTAIN is of type card, perhaps you should do :

```
Card* myCard = static_cast<Card*>(target);
myCard->openCard();
```

To be honest unless you actually post the relevant code it would be hard for anyone to help you. What does Card even look like ? (I don't care! XD)